# Optimizing SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

```
SELECT TOP 10 dic.item_cd,
              dic.item_knm,
              dic.item_enm
FROM tbus.dt_item_com dic
INNER JOIN tbus.mfProd mfp ON dic.item_cd LIKE mfp.prodId
INNER JOIN tbus.plu_category plc ON mfp.prodType LIKE plc.plc_prodType
WHERE (dic.item_knm LIKE '%%'
  OR (dic.item_enm LIKE '%%')
  AND (dic.item_cd NOT IN
         (SELECT TOP 0 dic.item_cd
          FROM tbus.dt_item_com dic
          INNER JOIN tbus.mfProd mfp ON dic.item_cd LIKE mfp.prodId
          INNER JOIN tbus.plu_category plc ON mfp.prodType LIKE plc.plc_prodType
          WHERE (dic.item_knm LIKE '%%'
                 OR dic.item_enm LIKE '%%')
          ORDER BY dic.item_cd DESC))
ORDER BY dic.item_cd DESC
```

This is the SQL query I'm trying to optimize.

What this query does is Inner Join three tables by item names (currently it's just '%%'. It's gonna be something like '%apple%' later on'). And, cuz this is for paging, it has NOT IN syntax in there too.

The problem here is there are two duplicated INNER JOIN & WHERE phrases - one in inside of NOT IN and the other in outside.  How can I remove this duplicated codes and make it faster :( ?

(It's based on SQL Server 2000)

Comment: what indexes do you have?

Comment: That does the TOP 0 mean? What's up with the NOT IN? Does it have special meaning? Are you attempting to do paging by exclusion??

Comment: dontamaso // unfortunately, there is no number index. Odering item_cd(item code) will be the way to index them.

Comment: usr // Yes. like I mentioned, this query is for paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer a different question (as per the comments): How to do paging on SQL Server? You normally use the row-Number function:

```
select * from (
 select *, row_number() over(order by something) r
 from T
) x
where r >= 10 and r < 20
```

Then, all your problems go away.

Comment: I'm aware of this solution... but the problem still exists. It's not 2008 version :(  Unfortunately, Row_number() is not supported.

Comment: Crap, I overlooked the sql 2000 tag. Can't believe this product is still being used?! Anyway, I'm not qualified to answer then. I'll edelete this shortly. Maybe you should just Google "SQL Server 2000" paging. All kinds of stuff comes up.

Comment: Nah, you don't have to delete it. Someone may find it useful :)

Comment: I also can't believe there are companies so afraid of following the current IT trends hahaha. Thank you for your effort tho!